# Serialize ManyToMany Mappings in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm implementing a RESTful webservice with Spring JPA and Hibernate. I have a simple Blog System, with a database table for the posts, the tags and the dependency between those (as many to many mapping). This is my Entity for the blog posts:

```
@Entity
public class Post {

//...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "posts_tags", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private List<Tag> tags;

//...
}
```

Now, if I'm requesting the blog posts using GET, the spring application returns this json:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/posts{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/posts/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "posts" : [ {
      "title" : "test title",
      "content" : "some test content",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/posts/1"
        },
        "tags" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/posts/1/tags"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

The spring application links the tags rather to include them in the json repsonse, what I would prefer. Is there a way to include the many to many mapping into the json response? Something like this:

```
"_embedded" : {
    "posts" : [ {
        "title" : "test title",
        "content" : "some test content",
        "tags" : [ {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "tag1"
        }, {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "tag2"
        }]
    } ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: could you show your servlet method (web controller method). What does app return in controller method? What lib is used for serialization? (just to see full picture).

Comment: I'm using Spring Data REST, so the controller methods are generated by spring. It's basically this spring guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: I guess the reference has its benefit, because often at the time of serialization db transaction is no longer available, thus attempting to access a relationship could produce NoTxAvailable exception

Comment: I can't really judge that, but loading the blog posts with an AJAX requests ends up in a lot more requests this way, as for each blog post the tags would have to be requested seperately. So if the reference is the way it should be done, is there another way to make this work?